# Is this category co-complete?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $R$ is a preorder in which objects are tuples $(X, \sim_{X})$ of a set $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim_{X}$ on $X$. Suppose also that $(X, \sim_{X}) \leq (Y, \sim_{Y})$ when:

- $X \subseteq Y$
- For any $x,x' \in X$ where $x \sim_{X} x'$ we have $x \sim_{Y} x'$.

Is $R$ co-complete?

Comment: For a category to be co-complete you need at least two things: Arbitary coproducts and coequalizers (this is the dual statement to: A category is complete if and only if it has arbitrary (small) products and equalizers, see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limit#ConstructionFromProductsAndEqualizers)). Since $R$ is a preorder, existence of coequalizers is trivial (every two parallel arrows $X\rightarrow Y$ are equal), hence you only need to check existence of coproducts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. The coproduct of a family $((X_i,\sim_{X_i}))$ is simply the union $(X,\sim_X)=(\cup X_i,\overline{\cup \sim_{X_i}}),$  where the overline indicates the transitive closure of the union. This transitive closure is an equivalence relation, so this gives an object of $R.$ Certainly each $(X_i,\sim_{X_i})\le (X,\sim_X),$ by construction. And if all the $(X_i,\sim_{X_i})$ are $\le$ some $(Y,\sim_Y),$ then $X_i\subseteq Y$ for every $i,$ which means $X=\cup X_i\subseteq Y;$ furthermore $\sim_{X_i}\subseteq \sim_Y$ for every $i,$ by a rephrasing of your definition, so that $\cup \sim_{X_i}\subseteq \sim_Y,$ and the same holds for the transitive closure $\sim_X,$ since $\sim_Y$ is transitive. As Alessandro comments, for a preorder cocompleteness is equivalent to the existence of small coproducts, so we are done.